# Joins to get books sold by publisher

Tags: sql, join, entity

I have several tables:

Book
Publisher
orderLine

I need to do a query that can give me total books sold, by publisher.

So what I need is to get a column that lists each publisher, a second column with the total number of times that publisher appears in the orderLine table. The orderLine table does not contain the publisherID, only the ISBN. The book table has ISBN as a key, and publisherID as a foreign key. The publisher table has publisherID as a primary key. I know this probably has to do with joins, but I have been trying for hours with no luck.

Comment: I haven't yet constructed the tables I am doing hypothetical queries for my project.

Comment: I think you will find using tables makes querying far easier